# What does each Facebook Ref querystring parameter mean?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone happen to know of an article that explains what each ref in facebook's querystring means? I've dug all over the place and can't find it.

<3 Facebook documentation
*/sarcasm*

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an unofficial list: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Ref

{edit} there's also official documentation for fb_source here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fb_source/ {/edit}

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ones I've found thus far:

TS - Top Search

NF - News Feed

MF - ???